# Heroku & HHVM & WordPress installation problems

Tags: wordpress, heroku, hhvm

I'm trying to install Heroku / HHVM / WordPress on a Debian 6 64 bits VPS to test this kind of setup for my blog (Nginx + MySQL + HP-FPM + Varnish + WordPress on another Debian 6 64 bits VPS) following the recent and promising guide done by [Xiao Yu](http://www.xyu.io/2014/06/wordpress-on-nginx-hhvm-with-heroku-buildpacks/) and available [on GitHub](https://github.com/xyu/heroku-wp).

I'm absolutelly new to Heroku/Ruby and I'm affraid I'm quite lost when something not expected is happening. The installation guide seemed to be straightforward, but it isn't clear which packages do I need to install first (PHP-FPM? Nginx? Or does this script install those by itself?) and I'm stuck on this step:

```
git push heroku production:master
```

When I execute that, I get this:

```
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 344, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (162/162), done.
Writing objects: 100% (344/344), 72.73 KiB, done.
Total 344 (delta 139), reused 342 (delta 139)

-----> PHP app detected

 !     ERROR: Could not resolve composer.lock requirement for HHVM 3.1.0,
       please adjust the version selector. The following runtimes are available:
       hhvm-3.2.0 php-5.5.11 php-5.5.12 php-5.5.13 php-5.5.14 php-5.5.15
       php-5.6.0RC4


 !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app

To git@heroku.com:xxxxxx-fortress-xxxx.git
 ! [remote rejected] production -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:xxxxxxx-fortress-xxxx.git'
```

I've tried to take a look at composer.json, edit it and include a

```
"php": "~5.5.11",
```

line on the require section, but that doesn't work... unless I have to do something before (update composer.lock? How?), which I'm not sure about.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HHVM 3.1.0 is not available (anymore), as the error message points out. You would however have to update `composer.lock` too.

Your best bet is to just update from the template; it's been fixed there: https://github.com/xyu/heroku-wp/commit/2a0ea2097597f72c401a63c070a14ec5031ffc9d

Comment: Thanks dzuelke, I've contacted Xiao through Twitter and he has been kind enough to tell exactly that. He has updated the repo and I've been able to install the package as indicated.